# How to detect reflexivity of the closure

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces, lebesgue-measure, locally-convex-spaces

Consider the space of continuous bounded functions on a bounded interval.

Its closure for the Lebesgue $L_p$ norm is reflexive when $1 < p < \infty$, but it is not reflexive for $p = 1$.

How can reflexivity of the closure be detected by just looking at the original vector space and the chosen norm?

What happens for the $p = \infty$ case in the above situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usually called *completion*, not *closure*. Closure adds elements from some   given metric space to its subset. Completion creates new abstract elements and adds them to the space.

When $p=\infty$, completion does not add anything to the space: $C[a,b]$ is already complete with respect to the $L^\infty$ norm. This space is not reflexive: one reason is that  its dual (the space of Radon measures on $[a,b]$) is not separable: the unit point masses form an uncountable uniformly separated set.

> How can reflexivity of the closure be detected by just looking at the original vector space and the chosen norm?

If the norm is  [uniformly convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_convex_space), then the completion is reflexive. Indeed, uniform convexity passes to the completion, and implies reflexivity.

If the norm is not uniformly convex (and is not a finite sum of uniformly convex norms, like $\|f\|_{L^2}+\|f'\|_{L^2}$), then you should expect the space to be nonreflexive. However, to actually prove this you will have to look at the completion. After all, nonreflexivity means there is something in the second dual that does not come from the completion of original space. If you don't look at the completion, how can you tell?